# how to make my own MPEG-DASH server?

Tags: nginx, mpeg-dash

I have already used the ffmpeg and mp4box to get the necessary file,just like the guild  [Making Your Own Simple MPEG-DASH Server](http://www.instructables.com/id/Making-Your-Own-Simple-DASH-MPEG-Server-Windows-10/).Then I put all the files include the MPD and the dash segments into my http server folder(nginx I used,the folder is **/wwwroot/default/).

But I can not play my video via player like [akamai player](http://players.akamai.com/dash/) or [dash-if-reference-player](http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/1.4.0/samples/dash-if-reference-player/).The url is right  because I can directly use "my domain/video/one_of_the_dash_segments.mp4" to play the video in Chrome.

Thank you a lot if you could tell me what should I do to fix this problem.

Comment: Pop-up you browser's console and check the network tab for errors. Did you enable CORS like in the example?

Comment: Thank you! I can see the error,"Failed to load http://****/manifest.mpd: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested ".        I add "add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" in my nginx.conf,and use "nginx -s reload" to active this configure.But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well,it seems that the [player](http://players.akamai.com/dash/) which I use does not support the dash segments generated by MP4Box.So I try to use another tool [bento4](http://www.bento4.com/developers/dash/) and put the output into my nginx's root folder.Then it works.